# Invalid pointer crash on delete, but different pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, gdb, free

My program crashes with an invalid pointer. When I run gdb with it, it tells me the address of the invalid pointer that caused the crash. The line it crashes on is a

```
delete some_pointer;
```

But when I print out the pointer right before deleting it, the address is not the same as the one gdb tells me is invalid. So is that some_pointer I'm deleting when it crashes not the pointer thats causing a problem? gdb says -

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfffea84 ***
```

So why would it crash on a free with a different address every time? I just want to make sure that I'm thinking correctly here.

Comment: Why do you tag `C` when you are using `delete` ?

Comment: What's the type of `some_pointer`?

Comment: The address is going to be different on every run. All addresses are.

Comment: Might want to show some of your other code like the declaration and allocation of `some_pointer` to make this more clear. If for example your pointer is uninitialized you might run into something like this ...

Comment: We need more code, I think the reasoning being diserned from gdb is besides the point. you more than likely have a logic/implementation error.

Comment: pmr - By "a different address every time" I meant the pointer I'm deleting and the pointer gdb says is invalid are different each time. Thank you all for the comments. I believe Lol4t0's suggestion is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly, the pointer was `delete`d before the delete you are looking at.  Deleting a pointer twice causes exactly the symptoms described.

Comment: But even if I delete it twice, shouldn't it still have the same address?

Comment: @Sterling:  I would not place too much weight on the actual pointer value.  First of all, that looks like the address of the pointer variable—not the pointer value (contents).  Secondly, the first delete is successful, so you probably do not know what the value was at that time.  Thirdly, another pointer value could have been assigned; without seeing some code, this is necessarily hypothetical speculation.  Fourth, the pointer value could vary from run to run for many reasons:  randomness (whether intentional or reaction to the environment) or SELinux reasons (which randomizes memory layout).

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
struct S
{
   int* p;
   ~S() { delete p;}
};

S* s;
std::cout << (void*)s;
delete s;
```

Probably, your program will crash while deleting `p`, but `s` will be printed. They will likely be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class with multiple inheritance, the address will be adjusted depending on the type of the pointer. `free` will need to use the base type, but the compiler should be able to do the proper conversion invisibly behind the scene.